# How to know which http server is this Clojure/ClojureScript project using? And how to make the HTTP server be `:dev-http`?

Tags: http, clojure, clojurescript, web-development-server, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

It works fine. I can watch changes on the UI on `localhost:3005`.

Based on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642964/while-using-shadow-cljs-to-watch-the-app-when-should-i-refresh-the-browser-to-s), I would like to understand better which HTTP server I am using.

Doing a `git grep`, I can find:

```clj
Pedros-MacBook-Air:balance pedro$ git grep ":dev-http"
Pedros-MacBook-Air:balance pedro$ git grep ":http"
shadow-cljs.edn:                                 :http-root   "public"
shadow-cljs.edn:                                 :http-port   3005
```

Hence, I suppose I can conclude the HTTP server is **not** `:dev-http`, right?

If so, how can I make `:dev-http` the default?

Just tweaking `shadow-cljs.edn` to add `:dev-http`?

Should I remove current `:http-root "public"` and `:http-port 3005`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:http-root` and `:http-port` in the `:devtools` part of the build config is the old (and deprecated) style of configuring http servers in shadow-cljs. `:dev-http` is the new notation.

So your config is identical to setting `:dev-http {3005 "public"}` (and removing the http parts from `:devtools`). They are functionally equivalent otherwise.