# How to handle the new HTTP configuration for shadow-cljs?

Tags: build, localhost, clojurescript, httpserver, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs,
and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command
`cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow`
for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

Things were working fine. I was used to watching changes on the UI on
`localhost:3005`.

But, [an answer from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73652120/how-to-know-which-http-server-is-this-clojure-clojurescript-project-using-and-h) indicated that the
project was using an old (and deprecated) HTTP configuration for
shadow-cljs.

On `shadow-cljs.edn` we had:

```clj
{:source-paths ["src" "dev"]

 :dependencies ...omitted..

 :nrepl        {:port 8230
                :nrepl-middleware [dirac.nrepl/middleware]}

 :builds       {:app {
                      :devtools {:after-load  app.core/main
                                 :http-root   "public"
                                 :http-port   3005
                                 :preloads    [shadow.cljs.devtools.client.hud
                                               day8.re-frame-10x.preload
                                               dirac.runtime.preload
                                               devtools.preload]}

}}}}}
```

After the build was complete, I would see the live application on
`localhost:3005`. The mini-buffer would direct me to see the
rendered page on the browser.

On `shadow-cljs.edn`, now, we  have:

```clj
{:source-paths ["src" "dev"]

 :dependencies ...omitted..

 :nrepl        {:port 8230
                :nrepl-middleware [dirac.nrepl/middleware]}

 :builds       {:app {
                      :devtools {:after-load  app.core/main
                                 :preloads    [shadow.cljs.devtools.client.hud
                                               day8.re-frame-10x.preload
                                               dirac.runtime.preload
                                               devtools.preload]}
                      :dev-http {3005 "public"} 
}}}}}
```

However, the workflow for development is different.

Emacs mini-buffer redirects me on the browser to a different address:
`http://localhost:9630/dashboard`

Also, old `localhost:3005` does not work, even though it is mentioned
on `:dev-http {3005 "public"}`.

1 - What is the new workflow to change the code and see the changes?

2 - Why is port `localhost:3005` not working anymore even though it is mentioned in the source code?

3 - What is the purpose of the dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[:dev-http](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#dev-http) is a top-level config. It is not part of a build config. It needs to sit at the same level as `:nrepl` and `:builds`.

```clj
{:source-paths ["src" "dev"]

 :dependencies ...omitted..

 :nrepl        {:port 8230
                :nrepl-middleware [dirac.nrepl/middleware]}

 :dev-http {3005 "public"} 

 :builds
 {:app
  {...
   :devtools
   {:after-load  app.core/main
    :preloads
    [day8.re-frame-10x.preload
     dirac.runtime.preload
     devtools.preload]}}}}}}
```